# Is this a parameter or a type?

Tags: c++, templates

In a sample code (below) I am wondering what is the parameter passed to the `getSocialSecurityNumber` in the `Citizen` class. Why is it `(Passkey<Government>)` and not `(Passkey<Government> x)`.

Is it related to class template / functor ?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class Passkey {
private:
    friend T;
    Passkey() {}
    Passkey(const Passkey&) {}
    Passkey& operator=(const Passkey&) = delete;
};

class Citizen {
public:
    string getSocialSecurityNumber(Passkey<Government>) const { return _socialSecurityNumber; };
                                   ^^^^ (here)

private:
    string _socialSecurityNumber;
};

class Government {
private:
    void printCitizenInfo(const Citizen &citizen) const;
};

void Government::printCitizenInfo(const Citizen &citizen) const {
    cout << "Citizen SSN: " << citizen.getSocialSecurityNumber(Passkey<Government>()) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Aha this is how "secure" code for government is written.

Comment: @Slava could you give me a little hint about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Passkey<Government>` is a type. The parameters is obviously not used, it has no name.

Comment: So what is the aim about it ? how is it used ?

Comment: The parameter \*is not\* used.

Comment: Ok if I understood, it is only related to force the signature for invoking the function getSocialSecurityNumber